# Reserve words in web.xml of servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, web.xml

I'm fairly new to servlets so I hope this isn't an obvious question.  So I have a simple Java servlet I've created in NetBeans using a template.  I have a context parameter I created in web.xml that lists allowed hosts (one of my request parameters is a URL which I'll compare against this list):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>allowedHosts</param-name>
    <param-value>
        http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/NOAA/CBOFS/MODELS/201206/nos.cbofs.fields.nowcast.20120612.t00z.nc?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
        http://www.google.com
        http://www.facebook.com
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I put only dummy URLs in like Google and Facebook, this works perfectly.  However, when I add the first URL, the Tomcat server cannot even deploy.  Looking at my logs, I see this at the top of a very long stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 19 column 146: The reference to entity "version" must end with the ';' delimiter.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "version" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Line 19 column 146 indeed points to the "version" portion of that long URL I have in the list of context parameters.  So obviously "version" is some kind of reserve word.  If I remove the "version" parameter from this URL, "request" is also a problem.

I can get around this by doing just `http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/` as the URL (because ultimately I want a list of hosts not specific URLs anyway), but I was wondering what one would have to do to get around this otherwise...  Is there a way to include URLs that have such "reserve words" in web.xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put "&amp;" (without the quotes) instead of the ampersands in your URL.

Hope this helps - DF

Edit: Try this:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>allowedHosts</param-name>
<param-value>
    http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/NOAA/CBOFS/MODELS/201206/nos.cbofs.fields.nowcast.20120612.t00z.nc?service=WMS&amp;version=1.3.0&amp;request=GetCapabilities
</param-value>
```

Edit2: PS These things are called "entities" in XML - do a Google for more info

Comment: I'm not sure if your answer worked properly.  Are you suggesting I encode the URLs?  Such as `&amp;` instead?

Comment: Yes, I will update my answer (I had a few goes at it as StackOverflow's editor was slightly fussy!)